# Bootstrap 4 image grid - white line between rows in Chrome & Safari

Tags: image, google-chrome, firefox, bootstrap-4, safari

I have made the following grid in Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row padding">
    <div id="workshop1" class="col-lg-6 nopadding">
      <img src="images/Werkstatt/image_05.jpg" class="img-fluid nopadding" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="workshop2" class="col-lg-6 nopadding">
          <img src="images/Werkstatt/image_06.jpg" class="img-fluid nopadding" alt="">
        </div>

        <div id="workshop3" class="col-lg-6 nopadding">
          <img src="images/Werkstatt/image_08.jpg" class="img-fluid nopadding" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div id="workshop4" class="col-lg-6 nopadding">
          <img src="images/Werkstatt/image_09.jpg" class="img-fluid nopadding" alt="">
        </div>

        <div id="workshop5" class="col-lg-6 nopadding">
          <img src="images/Werkstatt/image_07.jpg" class="img-fluid nopadding" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- end of first row -->

  <div class="row padding">
    <div id="workshop6" class="col-lg-3 nopadding">
      <img src="images/Werkstatt/image_01.jpg" class="img-fluid nopadding" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="workshop7" class="col-lg-3 nopadding">
      <img src="images/Werkstatt/image_04.jpg" class="img-fluid nopadding" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="workshop8" class="col-lg-3 nopadding">
      <img src="images/Werkstatt/image_02.jpg" class="img-fluid nopadding" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="workshop9" class="col-lg-3 nopadding">
      <img src="images/Werkstatt/image_03.jpg" class="img-fluid nopadding" alt="">
    </div>
  </div> <!-- end of second row -->
</div>
```

The css file looks like this:

```
.nopadding {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Now I have the problem, that there is a small white line between the right part of row 2 and row 3 in Safari and Chrome on my Mac. In Firefox everything looks fine:

**Firefox**
[image: Firefox]

**Chrome & Safari**
[image: Safari & Chrome]

Does anybody have an idea how fix this? All browsers are up to date.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Lars

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `display: block;` to your images or `float: left;`

Sometimes trying `font-size: 0;` or `line-height: 0;` works.

Comment: Thanks, `float: left;` did help for Safari, but it did not change anything in Chrome...

Comment: I edited my answer, sometimes you might need to try a few things. I have run into this before but forgot exactly what the issue was. Cross browser issues aren't fun.

Comment: I tried both, but it did not help. Finally I created another css class with a negative bottom-margin for the last row of images.

````margin-top: -0.25rem !important;````

Thanks a lot for your help!